# How i can use cPanel to upload php files and database?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

For couple of days i am trying to upload my php files and database to WebsitePanel but i can't. If anybody is familiar with WebsitePanel please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use cPanel then follow this step:

1. Login to cPanel
2. Click on File Manager
3. Select Web Root (public_html/www) and clock on Go.
4. Click on Upload on the top.
5. Click on Choose File to select the file which you have upload.

For database:

1. Click on phpMyAdmin on the home page of your cpanel.
2. Select the database which you have used on the left side of your phpMyAdmin interface.
3. Click on SQL and paste your MySql code on it.
4. Click go to run the code.