# Uploading a bootstrap project to the web server

Tags: php, bootstrapping

How to upload a project developed using bootstrap php and mysql on to a web hosting server? If anyone has the idea then pls help. I am new to this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial
[How i can use cPanel to upload php files and database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968193/how-i-can-use-cpanel-to-upload-php-files-and-database)

If you use cPanel then follow this step:

1. Login to cPanel
2. Click on File Manager
3. Select Web Root (public_html/www) and clock on Go.
4. Click on Upload on the top.
5. Click on Choose File to select the file which you have upload.

For database:

1. Click on phpMyAdmin on the home page of your cpanel.
2. Select the database which you have used on the left side of your phpMyAdmin interface.
3. Click on SQL and paste your MySql code on it.
4. Click go to run the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It really helped me.